# How can I know if the Google Analytics profile is the default one using Legato

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics a web-property may hold more than a single profile, in which case one of them is suppose to be defined as the default one (in GA you browse inside it you can see a [DEFAULT] tag by its name).

Using the Legato gem, is there a way of querying whether the profile is the default one or not? is there a way to pass parameters to add this information to the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this appears to be an API [limitation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-analytics-management-api/Q63lE8Dwaa4).

Browsing the [developer reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles) for the API v3, the profile representation contains no property indicating its status among siblings.

Comment: Thank you. At least not just my problem ;)
Just to be sure - say that the API will be added with that, Legato will automatically support it (if I followed the implementation, all properties are returned as given), right?

Comment: Unlikely. APIs follow a strict specification and typically don't change. Therefore, API wrappers like Legato map responses statically. If an API were to add a new call, support for it must be written in.

Comment: If it is added to the GA attributes returned by the API, `Legato::Management::WebProperty` has a method called `attributes` that returns a hash of any "leftover" keys/values returned that are not used explicitly (name, website_url, and account_id).

So, yes. If it's added, it should be there.